# Error-The request xml is too complex and its depth exceeds the maximum depth 32 undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am getting this error while running the below javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var siteUrl = '/projects/SharePoint2013-Demo/TimesheetManagementSystem/';
var oList = null;
var web = null;
var clientContext  = null;



function retrieveListItems(sender, args) {

var filterValue =document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_1c91c2d4_fbbb_4792_8507_ba589e5be222_SpListPicker_SelectionBox");
var StartDate=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_ed4beb82_8f7e_4389_bb35_a44188462aab_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");  
var EndDate=document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl41_g_07c2185d_e903_4010_8a84_b2d9536a5549_DateFilterPicker_DateFilterPickerDate");
alert(filterValue.value );
alert(StartDate.value);
alert(EndDate.value);


    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TimeSheetList');
    clientContext.load(oList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.LoadList), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        


}



function LoadList(sender, args)
{
           var  camlQuery= new SP.CamlQuery();
                   camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Where><And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>Vikash Kumar</Value></Eq><Geq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2015-07-13T12:00:00Z</Value></Geq></And><Leq><FieldRef Name='Date' /><Value Type='DateTime'>2015-07-20T12:00:00Z</Value></Leq></And></Where>");  

   camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlQuery);

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);


    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));   

}


 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';


    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var ID= oListItem.get_id();
                alert(ID);
                }
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}


</script>

<button type="button" onclick="retrieveListItems()">Approve!</button>
```

What is the reason, where am I doing wrong??

Comment: Your `view_Xml` is missing it's beginning and ending `<View>` elements

Comment: After adding also it is giving the same error...